# Changing hostname without errors

Tags: networking, hostname

I tried to change my hostname according to [this](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/07/how-to-change-the-hostname-of-a-linux-system/) guide for Debian based system:

1. I edited `/etc/hostname`
2. I ran `/etc/init.d/hostname start`

Though there are errors. Always when I write a `sudo` command it tells me it can't recognize the hostname. After I restarted the system, the graphical environment wasn't working, the `startx` command wasn't successful. So, I changed the hostname back to the old name.

Can I change the hostname without errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your new hostname can't be resolved to an ip address. There are basically two solutions for your problem.

First one but little bit more complex solution is to adjust the hostname in `/etc/hosts` as well. You will have to adjust `/etc/hosts` every time you change your hostname.

The second and simpler solution is to install [nss-myhostname](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/nss-myhostname/). The debian package name is `libnss-myhostname` so just install it with `apt-get install libnss-myhostname`. This will allow you to always resolve your current hostname.

Comment: I installed it. What should I run after installation?

Comment: @xralf nothing, that's all you need to do. You should now be able to change your hostname and should be able to resolve it via nss. Just try to run sudo and the error should be gone

Comment: There may be running programs whose NSS implementation has already read `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.   Those programs may need to be restarted.

Comment: If you want to permanently change your hostname, does doing `hostname NEW_HOST.TLD` suffice if I've already installed `libnss-myhostname`?

Comment: @AlixAxel no it just changes the hostname temporarily till the next reboot